# Counting Python files with bash and awk always returns zero

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to get a number of python files on my desktop and I have coded a small script for that. But the awk command does not work as is have expected.
script

```
ls -l | awk '{ if($NF=="*.py") print $NF; }' | wc -l
```

I know that there is another solution to finding a number of python files on a PC but I just want to know what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: What does `ls -l` output?

Comment: `ls -l *.py|wc -l` you don't need awk code..

Comment: `ls *.py | wc -l` you don't need long-format listing either. It'd be even better to [avoid parsing `ls` at all](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) (`ls` is really intended for *displaying* lists of files to a user, not getting them programmatically), but as long as you don't have any filenames with newlines in them this'll work. BTW, original problem is that in the `awk`, script `*.py` is matched as a literal string rather than a glob (wildcard) pattern.

Comment: `a=(*.py); echo ${#a[@]}`

Comment: I've edited the question title. "Bash script does not behave in expected way" is a useless title, because it doesn't distinguish your question from _every other question using the bash tag_; someone getting expected behavior wouldn't be here. Remember, the purpose of a title is to help other people with the same problem find your question and learn from its answers so they don't need to write a new question. If you couldn't identify a preexisting question having the same title as making yours unnecessary from the title alone, then that title wouldn't be useful to anyone else either.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for making it clear for everyone :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -l | awk '{ if($NF=="*.py") print $NF; }' | wc -l
```

Your code does count of files *literally* named `*.py`, you should deploy regex matching and use correct GNU `AWK` syntax, after fixing that, your code becomes

```
ls -l | awk '{ if($NF~/[.]py$/) print $NF; }' | wc -l
```

note `[.]` which denote *literal* `.` and `$` denoting end of string.
Your code might be further ameloriated, as there is not need to use `if` here, as pattern-action will do that is

```
ls -l | awk '$NF~/[.]py$/{ print $NF; }' | wc -l
```

Morever you might easily implemented counting inside GNU `AWK` rather than deploying `wc -l` as follows

```
ls -l | awk '$NF~/[.]py$/{t+=1}END{print t}'
```

Here, `t` is increased by `1` for every describe line, and after all is processed, that is in `END` it is `print`ed. Observe there is no need to declare `t` variable in GNU `AWK`.

Comment: Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Comment: Your code is overly verbose. make it ::::: awk '{ t += /[.]py$/ } END { print t }' :::: you're checking the tail anyway, so $NF is implicit, and you can make "t" directly add in the outcome of the pattern evaluation instead of having to split pattern + action block.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to parse the output of `ls`, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Beyond that your awk script is failing because `$NF=="*.py"` is doing a literal string partial comparison of the last sting of non-spaces against `*.py` when you probably wanted a regexp comparison such as `$NF~/*.py$/` and your `print $NF` would fail for any file names containing spaces.

If you really want to involve awk in this for some reason then, assuming the list of python files doesn't exceed `ARG_MAX`,  it'd be:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print ARGC-1; exit}' *.py
```

but you could just do it in bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=(*.py)
echo "${#files[@]}"
```

or if you want to have a pipe to `wc -l` for some reason and your files can't have newlines in their names then:

```
printf '%s\n' *.py | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gfind . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.py" -print0 | 

     {m,g}awk 'END { print   NR }' RS='\0' FS='^$'
   or
     {m,g}awk 'END { print --NF }' RS='^$' FS='\0'

879
```